# Create a Circular Layout with moving ImageViews inside

Tags: android, android-studio, animation

I want to create a circular layout with some imageviews inside and the imageviews are moving non stop by animation but I have no idea how to.
**below image is what I need**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qMYV.jpg

It is going to be a lottery application which i didnt find any code sample for something like the image above.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance